# Tool for "ordinary people" be able to run web tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Which tool would you say have the fastest learning-curve for "ordinary people" (ie, people whose experience with computers is basically using Faceboook) to be able to write "web tests" (for instance, "access this site, type [X] on this input field, press button, wait 5 seconds, check if the response contains 'OK'").

I'm looking for something that could be teachable in 5-10 hours. I don't care if it results in a stable and very reliable test. This is just to be an alternative for a "monkey tester" while integration tests aren't developed.

The simplest idea I can think is a macro-recorder (recommending the tester to wait a longer time for things that may take longer) and taking a screenshot in the end (the tester would select parts of the image that are important).

Is there anything better than that (or at least that)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 5-10 hours learning [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for basics tests should be more then enough.

- It's free
- Huge userbase, lots of learning materials and ready to use examples
- No installation needed, just add-on to firefox (or other browsers as well)
- A little familiarity with html and javascript enables you to write rather complex tests for your web application

If for some reasons Selenium IDE is not an option for you you might check products like e.g. [Ghost inspector](http://ghostinspector.com) or [Visual Studio Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/test/manual-tests/test-manager/record-play-back-manual-tests).